# How to change WooCommerce thumbnail crop position?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, crop, image-size

I'm trying to change WooCommerce thumbnail crop position. I found this code can help to change the size:

```
add_action( 'init', 'yourtheme_woocommerce_image_dimensions', 1 );

/**
 * Define image sizes
 */
function yourtheme_woocommerce_image_dimensions() {
    $catalog = array(
        'width'     => '100',   // px
        'height'    => '100',   // px
        'crop'      => 0
    );

    // Image sizes
    update_option( 'shop_catalog_image_size', $catalog );       // Product category thumbs
}
```

I did some try like change crop **`0`** to **`array("center", "bottom")`** but it's not working:

```
function yourtheme_woocommerce_image_dimensions() {
    $catalog = array(
    'width'   => '300', // px
    'height'  => '400', // px
    'crop'    => 'array("center", "bottom")'
  );

  // Image sizes
  update_option( 'shop_catalog_image_size', $catalog );     // Product category thumbs
}
```

And also this without success:

```
if (function_exists( 'add_image_size' )){
  add_image_size( 'shop_catalog', 300, 400, array( 'center', 'bottom' ) );
}
```

Is there anyway I can change it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change existing images sizes (crop option) within your active child theme or theme, you need to use `'after_switch_theme'` WordPress hook.

Since WordPress 3.9+ an awesome new feature among many, is the added ability to now control crop position of images uploaded in WordPress.
I don't know if crop potion advanced option is available to woocommerce images sizes, you will have to test it.

The available options for crop position are:

```
left top
left center
left bottom
right top
right center
right bottom
center top
center center
center bottom
```

So based on [**this snippet**](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/set-woocommerce-image-dimensions-upon-theme-activation/) from wooThemes and and (this relative new) crop options of WordPress, you can try this:

```
function yourtheme_woocommerce_image_dimensions() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( ! isset( $_GET['activated'] ) || $pagenow != 'themes.php' ) {
        return;
    }
    $catalog = array(
        'width'     => '300',   // px
        'height'    => '400',   // px
        'crop'      => array( 'center', 'bottom' ) // New crop options to try.
    );
    /* $single = array(
        'width'     => '600',   // px
        'height'    => '600',   // px
        'crop'      => 1        // true
    );
    $thumbnail = array(
        'width'     => '120',   // px
        'height'    => '120',   // px
        'crop'      => 0        // false
    ); */
    // Image sizes
    update_option( 'shop_catalog_image_size', $catalog );       // Product category thumbs
    /* update_option( 'shop_single_image_size', $single );      // Single product image
    update_option( 'shop_thumbnail_image_size', $thumbnail );   // Image gallery thumbs */
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'yourtheme_woocommerce_image_dimensions', 1 );
```

*You will need to paste this code snippet in function.php file of your active child theme or theme…*

You can comment/uncomment the code (or remove some portions) to feet your needs. This code will overwrite define options in WooCommerce settings > Products > Display (Product Images).

> **ACTIVATION:**
>   You will need to **switch your active theme** to another and then switch back to activate it.

References:

- [Set WooCommerce image dimensions upon theme activation](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/set-woocommerce-image-dimensions-upon-theme-activation/)