# woocommerce archive ( category) thumbnail crop center

Tags: wordpress, image, function, woocommerce, thumbnails

I want to crop thumbnail of WooCommerce products in Archive,category,shop pages.
I want crop position to be center center.
I visited link below and nothing changed.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236848/how-to-change-woocommerce-thumbnail-crop-position)
The image of single page shouldn't be cropped.
Please Help.

Comment: Have you switched your active theme to another and then switch back to activate it (as indicated at the end of the answer)? … Also if you are using a custom theme (premium theme) in which that hook is already used, you will need first to remove the action from it before…

Comment: ty. I have only Salmon theme and it's child. Should I install another theme to switch between them?

Comment: Try to put back the default Wordpress theme like "twenty-fivteen" or similar *(in case of problem in your main parent theme, it can be useful)* … make a database backup before switching… once installed "twenty-fivteen", switch to it and then switch back to your child theme. This is the way to activate effectively the code you are using…

Comment: I did as you said. but yet nothing changed.

Comment: So sorry, I don't know what is going wrong in your web site, as my code really works.