# How to resize thumbnails in woocommerce lightbox

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, lightbox

I have been trying to resize the thumbnails in lightbox but can't figure it out.
My current thumbnails are cropped and are about 50x30 px.
I need them to be square like 50x50.
I looked online for an hour but can't seem to find anything that works.
Below is a screenshot of the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yltym.jpg

Thanks for any help

Comment: you have to edit the css for the lightbox.

Comment: There is the option in the woo commerce settings to set the width and height of the image in woo commerce

Answer (score 0):

You can change the sizes of WooCommerce thumbnails by going to the WordPress admin and navigating to `WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display`. Then, adjust the sizes of WooCommerce Thumbnails. You'll also need to regenerate the thumbnails using a plugin, like [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/).

There's more information at the [WooCommerce Docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/fixing-blurry-product-images/#section-6).

Additionally, if those settings don't do it for you, you can drop in a function to adjust the WooCommerce thumbnails further. See this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38241452/3072442).

Comment: Thank you. I've already done this but it does not seem to apply to the lightbox thumbnails. I would like to know where the lightbox thumbnails settings are located (which file?). Thanks